# UndefinedFunctionError when creating LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Hello I’m trying to create my first LiveView in Phoenix

I have:

*router.ex*

```
scope "/", TestWeb do
  pipe_through :browser
  live "/app", AppLive
end
```

*app_live.ex*

```
defmodule TestWeb.AppLive do
  use TestWeb, :live_view
  
  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    test
    """
  end

  def mount(_params, _session, _socket) do
  end
end
```

but I get this error

```
UndefinedFunctionError at GET /app

function TestWeb.AppLive.__live__/0 is undefined (module TestWeb.AppLive is not available)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a socket from the mount.

```
  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
```